# Is it possible to allow people (not registered) just view a certain area in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have things in my mind: is it possible to allow people  to just view a certain area in wordpress?

thanks all

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely plugins that could help you with this. One of which appears to be (http://wpusersplugin.com/). Look around and you are likely to find the plugin that's right for you.

You can also alter parts of your theme with the function `is_user_logged_in`. If there are parts of your theme or site that you only want logged in users to see, wrap it in the following:

```
<?php 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{
   // Here's the stuff for logged in users
}
else
{
   // Here's the stuff for users not logged in
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

oh, yes, you can use custom post or using category method to do that. If you are using category, then all you need is to call up the category that you want to show to part of the people and hide the rest.

Comment: thank's for your answer. it make me better. can you show how i do it? i appreciate for your help.i'm just new in wp.